# What's the correct transformation for Lambert Conformal Conic for Mexico?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, mexico, lambert-conformal-conic

I have a shp archive without the .prj file. I don´t know the proyection of this shp, but I think it is in lambert conformal conic. Can anybody helpme to proyect this shp? i´ve tried to proyect it in wgs84 utm 16N and geografic wgs84, but i have no success. this shp is from Quintana Roo, México. I´m working in qgis

Comment: Check this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/69203/is-it-possible-to-change-crs-without-the-prj-file/69291#69291

Comment: In oder to reconize if your layer is in INEGI´s LCC the x coordinate must be greater than  2,500,000 meters (for the zone you are working on). If it is smaller than  1,000,000 meters the SRC must be UTM. In the answer cited above you will fin the parameters for INEGI´s CCL, and you have to include it as a User defined CRS.

Answer (score 3):

Two Lambert conformal conic definitions for Mexico were recently added to the [EPSG Geodetic Parameter registry](http://www.epsg-registry.org). Both have the same projection parameters, but are based upon different geographic coordinate reference systems. The projection parameters are:

```
central meridian / longitude of origin: -102.0
latitude of origin: +12.0
standard parallel 1: +17.5
standard parallel 2: +29.5
false easting: 2500000.0 m
false northing: 0.0 m
```

The two geographic coordinate reference systems are both ITRF-based and have transformations to WGS 84 with parameters equal to zeroes.

Note: I'm on the subcommittee that maintains the registry.

Comment: This is really good news when and how can I get more information about these EPSG codes, finally after many years this happens.

Comment: http://www.epsg-registry.org/ is the place to look for. But note that +towgs84 parametres are treated seperately by EPSG, and confusingly have their own EPSG-code.